# onTouchEvent cannot @Override in fragment

Tags: android-fragments

The method onTouchEvent(MotionEvent) of type FindPeopleFragment must override or implement a supertype method.
Is there any way to fix it rather than removing the @Override as i suspect removing it is the cause that make the GestureDetector dont work.

public class FindPeopleFragment extends Fragment implements OnGestureListener{

```
private GestureDetector gDetector;
ImageView iv1;

public FindPeopleFragment(){}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_find_people, container, false);
    gDetector = new GestureDetector(this);
    iv1=(ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    return rootView;
}
@Override
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me) {
        return gDetector.onTouchEvent(me);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent start, MotionEvent finish, float xVelocity, float yVelocity) {
        if (start.getRawY() < finish.getRawY()) {
            Log.i("fling", "if");
            //((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_place_holder)).setImageResource(R.drawable.down);
            //startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),MainActivity.class));
        } else {
            Log.i("fling", "else");
            //((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_place_holder)).setImageResource(R.drawable.up);
            //startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),Secc.class));
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent arg0, MotionEvent arg1, float arg2,
            float arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

   }
```

Comment: first line shows an error which i got.